# Getting Input in Python In hackerearth

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was solving a question on hackerearth with the following input type:
hackerearth.

```
1
3
1 2 3
```

First line of the input will contain T (no. of test cases). Then every test case will contain two lines. First line will have the value of N then the next line will have N space separated integers of set. 
this sample input size can increase according to the number to test cases we want to run for example if it is 2 than input can be;

```
2
3
1 2 3
4
1 2 3 4
```

so how to get the input so that i can proceed for the logic.
here what i tried:

```
test = input();
for i in range(len(test)):
    numberSize = input();
    for i in range(len(numberSize)):
       li = list(input.split());
print(li)
```

but this always return value for the first test case that is [1,2,3], please help me how to take the input from the hackerearth console

Comment: you want to be able to get some input like that "inputted by hand" or you have to parse a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
test = int(input())
for __ in range(test):
    numberSize = input()
    li = input.split()
```

The first input is for total number of test cases, and we are iterating the total number of test cases. They have mentioned in in each test cases there are two inputs, which we are getting it inside the `for` loop.